# Play 2.6 with Electron App - CORS

Tags: playframework, electron

I'm having the Invalid CORS problem with Play Framework.

`[warn] p.f.c.CORSFilter - Invalid CORS request;Origin=Some(file://);Method=POST;Access-Control-Request-Headers=None`

How can I configure to make it work with Electron App?

this is my current `application.conf`:

```
play.application.loader = "modules.ApplicationLoaderConfig"
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = null,       # This means "all"
  allowedHttpMethods = null,   # This means "all"
  exposedHeaders = ["Authorization", "Content-Length", "Content-Type", "Content-disposition"],
  preflightMaxAge = 7 days
}
```

I also tried removing the filters..  leaving only:

```
play.application.loader = "modules.ApplicationLoaderConfig"
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
```

But still can't get it to work.

On the electron side, I also tried with the `webSecurity` options:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
  });
```

I tried both `false` and `true`, but made no difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this configuration

```
play.filters.cors.serveForbiddenOrigins = true
```

Actually, there are some issues with using Play with  Electron Apps, because when they request something the origin is set as "file" and by default Play don't allow this.

See these links for reference.

1. https://github.com/Hub-of-all-Things/HAT2.0/pull/39
2. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8037
3. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/7341

Hope this helps!